# Using Stack Exchange OpenID  on blogger.com fails: "Your OpenID credentials could not be verified."

Tags: support, bug, status-declined, openid, blogger

I'm trying to add a comment to a post I read on `blogger.com`. Here is the post:
http://hacksoflife.blogspot.com/2006/01/iswindowvisible-can-be-deceiving.html#comment-form

I try to add the comment using the OpenID URL `https://openid.stackexchange.com/`, but it fails. Here is what it says when I use that URL:

> Do you wish to share your information with www.blogger.com?

I click confirm and then it brings me back to the `blogger.com` page where it says "Your OpenID credentials could not be verified."

I don't know why this is happening. My normal browser is Firefox, but I also tried in a virtual machine using Internet Explorer. It's the same in both. I also tried the URLs that are given on the Stack Exchange page, but they don't work either.

```
<link rel="openid2.provider" href="https://openid.stackexchange.com/openid/provider">
<link rel="openid2.local_id" href="https://openid.stackexchange.com/user/12345-edited">
```

How do I post comments to `blogger.com` using my Stack Exchange OpenID?

```
Authenticated To    Authenticated to meta.stackoverflow.com     1.2.3.4     6 mins ago
Authenticated To    Authenticated to www.blogger.com    1.2.3.4     1 hour ago
Authenticated To    Authenticated to www.blogger.com    1.2.3.4     1 hour ago
Authenticated To    Authenticated to www.blogger.com    1.2.3.4     1 hour ago
Authenticated To    Authenticated to www.blogger.com    1.2.3.4     1 hour ago
Authenticated To    Authenticated to www.blogger.com    1.2.3.4     1 hour ago
Login   Logged In   1.2.3.4     1 hour ago
```

Comment: This is super annoying. On my StackExchange OpenID page I can see these similar records for Authenticating to blogger.com, yet on the person's blog it says "Your OpenID credentials could not be verified". I don't want to use social media accounts to validate on public blog sites, that just feels wrong.

Answer (score -1):

That relying party appears to be failing OpenId discovery pretty spectacularly.  Not much I can do from this end, unfortunately.  [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)-ing this accordingly.

Comment: Would you mind sending an official-ish email to blogger with the details so they are at least aware of it?  Sending one as a user is likely to get them to blame stackexchange, rather than looking into it further.

Comment: I disagree. I'm trying to get spring-security to accept OpenID for a project, testing with my stackexchange OpenID. If I read section 11.2 of the OpenID 2.0 spec (http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html) correctly, the XRDS document found after applying discovery to the claimed ID (https://openid.stackexchange.com/user/11111-1111....) should contain a <Type>.../signon</Type> service element. It does not, and I think this is why spring-security rejects it. My Google ID is accepted, so my setup can't be completely wrong. ;) And I guess blogspot rejects them for the same reason.

Comment: My problem is I can't comments on Blogger using OpenID through my blog root http://www.techews.com , The error message is "Your OpenID credentials could not be verified"

Can anyone help me to comment on blogger using  my own blog www.techews.com

Thanks